# I don't understand lambdas functions in comprehension lists

Tags: python, lambda, parameters, list-comprehension

I can't understand how lambdas in comprehension lists works.

Please help me undestand this mechanism, and sorry but I'm learning right now and the explications that I can find online are not really clear to me.

```
def times_two(a): return a * 2
def times_three(a): return a * 3

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]

both_functions = [times_two, times_three]

for number in numbers:
  print(list(map((lambda x: x(number)), both_functions)))
```

What does *(lambda x: x(number))* do exacly, why is there a second x, what kind of parameter is?

Other example:

```
is_even_list = [lambda a=x: a * 10 for x in range(0, 6)]
for item in is_even_list:
    print(item())
```

Why here there is an *a=x*, usually lambdas doesn't have only one parameter?

The last one:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [lambda: _ for _ in A]
C = [_() for _ in B]
print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
```

Here what does *_()* do?

Comment: It must be said that it’s no wonder you’re confused, especially if you’re just learning.  These mechanisms are purely for ‘entertainment’, and should *never* be used in proper / production code.  These are only toy examples designed to twist your mind a bit. Success!  :-)

Comment: This would be a nice pattern to capture in the `operator` module, though. There's already a function `methodcaller`, where `methodcaller('f')(obj) == obj.f()`. Something like `map(caller(number), both_functions)` would be the same as the code in the first example, with `caller(number)(f) == f(numerals)`.

Comment: A more conventional parameter name might make it less confusing: `map(lambda f: f(number), both_functions)`, where `f` suggests "function" more strongly than `x` did. This still requires some familiarity with the concept of higher-order functions, though.

Answer (score 0):

The lists you're iterating over contain functions. Inside the iteration, you call the function in the current iteration item.

```
lambda x: x(number)
```

means that it receives a function in `x`, and then calls that function with `number` as the argument.

```
for item in is_even_list:
    print(item())
```

loops over the functions in `is_even_list`, and calls each of those functions.

```
[_() for _ in B]
```

`_` is just a variable name, although conventionally it's only used for iterations where you don't use the iteration item. `B` contains a list of functions, so this calls each of those functions and returns a list of the results.

Answer (score 0):

> What does `(lambda x: x(number))` do exactly

In terms of the comprehension, nothing specific. It is an argument of `map()`

> why is there a second x, what kind of parameter is?

It is a callable function object.

> Why here there is an a=x

It seems to be defining a partial function with a parameter for the `range()`. That syntax is new to me...

If you remove `=x`, then you get an error `missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'`, which is the same error if you had defined a regular function `def foo(a):` and just called `foo()` in the loop.

> usually lambdas doesn't have only one parameter

They are in-line functions, so no, they can have as many as necessary.

> what does _() do

`_` is just a variable. It can be assigned to a callable. `_()` calls a function named `_`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map((lambda x: x(number)), both_functions))
```

map loops over the items defined in both_functions which means for each number it loops over times_two and times_three function. ie: when number is 1, it produces output [times_two(1), times_three(1)] equals [2, 3]

Comment: Thanks Lalitha!
Do you mean that map iterate every sub function of both_functions and replacing the x?
Is it a specific mechanism between mep and lambda?

Comment: yes to your first question. first argument for map is a function lambda x: x(number) and second is a list. lambda function is executed for each element in the list and returns an object.